# VBA code not limited to designated columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to limit the following code to only columns 6 and 7, but it works for the entire sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim lOld As Long

    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler 

    On Error Resume Next

    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

    On Error GoTo exitHandler 

    If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler    

    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then

       'do nothing

    Else

      Application.EnableEvents = False

      newVal = Target.Value

      Application.Undo

      oldVal = Target.Value

      Target.Value = newVal

      If Target.Column = 6 _
          Or Target.Column = 7 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
          'do nothing
        Else
          If newVal = "" Then
            'do nothing
          Else
            lOld = Len(oldVal)
            If Left(newVal, lOld) = oldVal Then
              Target.Value = newVal
            Else
               Target.Value = oldVal _
                    & ", " & newVal
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If

    If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
    Else

    lOld = Len(oldVal)

    If Left(newVal, lOld) = oldVal Then
        Target.Value = newVal
    Else
        Target.Value = oldVal _
          & ", " & newVal
    End If

    End If
exitHandler:

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have code duplicated both inside your test for `INTERSECT` and later outside that test. There are some tests for column outside, so I'm not sure why it's triggering anyway... There also seems to be an extra `End If` I can't figure out so I'm not sure how it was even executing.

I've rewritten removing superfluous nested Ifs and whatnot. I've added comments mostly just to help me out while I was rewriting, but they may serve useful for future edits.

This code runs only for cells of type `xlCellTypeAllValidation` in columns 6 and 7. If you don't need to limit to just `xlCellTypeAllValidation` cells, then remove that from the main `If` test.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim lOld As Long

    'Exit routine if more than one cell was changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler 

    'Shut off errors, and attempt to grab xlCellTypeAllValidation cells
    'If no cells are of type xlCellTypeAllValidation then exit routine
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler    

    'If the cell changed is xlCellTypeAllValidation AND in columns 6 or 7 Then run code
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing AND (Target.Column = 6 OR Target.Column = 7) Then

        'Shut off events
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Capture old and new values to variables
        newVal = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldVal = Target.Value

        'undo the undo
        Target.Value = newVal

        'If the cell used to hold a value and it was changed to a new value (not null)
        If oldVal <> "" AND newVal <> "" Then       

            'Test to see if the change didn't affect the contents of the cell
            lOld = Len(oldVal)
            If Left(newVal, lOld) = oldVal Then
                Target.Value = newVal
            Else 'They've truly changed the content, so bring in the old content and append the new with a comma
                Target.Value = oldVal & ", " & newVal
            End If
        
        End If      
    End If

exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```